# How do i install openLink virtuoso on windows?

Tags: windows, bash, perl, powershell, virtuoso

I am trying to install [OpenLink Virtuoso (Open Source Edition)](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) on Windows but didn't make to install it correctly.

What I have tried: First I follow all the step at [Installation steps for OpenLink Virtuoso on Windows](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSMakeWindows#Prerequisites), which are as below --

1. Cygwin bash with developer tools (gawk, flex, bison) installed.
2. Active Perl, available from [ActivePerlLink](http://www.activestate.com/ActivePerl)
3. OpenSSL version 0.97 static libraries for Windows and header files.

-- but that doesn't help me so I have googled for another and I found this link [Steps to install OpenLink Virtuoso](https://pythonhosted.org/SuRF/integration/virtuoso.html) for install OpenLink Virtuoso 5

but I am stuck at step 4

> Execute from the shell:
>
> ```
> $ cd c:\virtuoso\database
>
> $ virtuoso-t -f virtuoso.ini //
> ```

It gives me an error on Cygwin64 Terminal

```
 /cygdrive/c/virtuoso/virtuoso-opensource-win32-20120802/virtuoso-opensource/database
$ virtuoso -t -f virtuoso.ini
-bash: virtuoso: command not found
```

and in PowerShell windows, it will be giving me an error as below

```
 virtuoso-t -f virtuoso.ini
virtuoso-t : The term 'virtuoso-t' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ virtuoso-t -f virtuoso.ini
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtuoso-t:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Anybody, please help me to install this open source version of OpenLink Virtuoso.

I have googled but didn't find a good source to install it correctly.

Comment: The first guide you followed comes from Virtuoso's creator (and my employer), [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), and should be considered authoritative. We would appreciate an alert of any errors you may find in that guide, optimally sent to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/) and/or posted in a [Support Case which may be opened at no cost](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Comment: Note as well that the first guide you followed was not for installation, but for building from source. The recommended pre-built binary installation is a simple ZIP extraction, and addition of the extracted `/bin/` subdirectory to your `$PATH`. One more note -- the binary is `virtuoso-t.exe`, not `virtuoso.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that you haven't done step 3. properly:

- Add `c:\virtuoso` to system *PATH*

How did you do this? Does it show `c:\virtuoso` if you enter `$PATH`?

Comment: I have added that path to $PATH but yet getting same error

Comment: Okay, but why did you not do that before when it is part of the installation process? We now have no idea which parts of the installation were successful. It would be much better if you gave a more accurate account of what you did and what the results were instead of waiting while I made guesses.

Comment: thanks, I have already done that step but giving the wrong path its actually in the bin path so I have added that path to system path and now it will work. What mistake actually I have made that the virtuoso-t is in bin path so I have added only the path c:\virtuoso. so I have added up to the bin path and now its working.thanks for your help.

Comment: @vimalDev: I was surprised that the prescribed path was `c:\virtuoso`. There is a Linux convention that the "binaries" will be in a `bin` subdirectory but there is no penalty for breaking that convention so I couldn't be certain. The blame lies with the author of the guide, and you should write them a note that includes a link to this *Stack Overflow* page.

Comment: @vimalDev: Where is `virtuoso.exe` or `virtuoso.bat` or similar?

Comment: it's not available in the opensource version of OpenLink Virtuoso

Comment: In the pre-built binary distribution of VOS (Virtuoso Open Source Edition), the binary is `virtuoso-t.exe`, found in the `bin` subdirectory of the ZIP expansion.